# Structure types in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

As I know SQL Server doesn't support structure types that contains another types,
for example you can't make something like this

```
create type User as(UserId int, Name varchar(10), Address varchar(255))
```

and then use it:

```
declare @user User
set @user.UserId = 10
...
```

Maybe someone knows any library/framework that helps to emulate this behavior, for example it can be some set of functions that use XML data-type to hold in it values and retrieve them.

The problem that I'm trying to solve is passing large number of parameters between stored procedures. I have procedure that accept nearly 30 parameters than make some logic and path this parameters to another procedure, then second procedure make some logic and path parameters to third procedure. Then requirements changed and new parameters should be add to all procedures. With structure data-types it transforms to just adding new fields in data-type. And another plus is readability.

Comment: I don't know of any other option to create structured types in sql server... Maybe someone else will have an answer more suited for your needs.

Comment: I use XML parameters for such things.

Comment: @RogerWolf: Nice! I wonder why I didn't think about it myself... [palmface]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good day,

My first guess is that you need user defined table type, as other mentioned. but in any case you are wrong and you can create new types that contains other types. For example I use "complex number" type which I create using SQLCLR.

You can see a simple code here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15651/Creating-User-Defined-Data-Types-in-SQL-Server

> this is not the code that I use :-) I just find this on Google now.

To clarify, the "complex number" is build from 2 simple decimal numbers, that mean we use two types to create out user defined data type :-)

> I use other types as well for example another one is BIGBIGINT. I have a very big table which need integers bigger than BIGINT... I created another type BIGBIGINT which use two BIGINT types.

**I hope this useful :-)**

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use such types when executing the stored procedure from a c# code? (using ado.net or an ORM)

Comment: Hi Ronen. Please ignore my question, I've found the relevant MSDN pages.

Comment: Good day Zohar Peled,
Since your new type is not mapped with other ORM for example like Entity Framework, it need more work use it directly, but this is the clean way theoretically  (Using Override to existing elements in classes for example)
Therefore the simple solution is...

* i will write another comment since the website cut it... this is not a good interface for tutorials :-) just for short messages

Comment: Good day Zohar,
The use of any type is depend on the way you declared and configure the type.

to simplify the discussion let's talk about another common type: point. You can see the code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8s4s5dz(v=vs.90).aspx

Option 1: You can use simple query from any client like using
INSERT INTO test_table (column1) VALUES ('1:2')

Option 2 (which I recommend on most cases like this): Use simple SP. You can pass a table-value-parameter to the SP, or just several parameters, as best fits your need.

Comment: thanks, It's always a pleasure (even in English :-))